# Private Docker Registry: 'x509: certificate signed by unknown authority' only for Windows images

Tags: docker

While trying to pull Windows images from a Private Docker Registry, I'm getting the following error

```
x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I've installed the proper certificate and I can pull Linux images without any issue, but for some reason I'm unable to pull Windows ones.

My co-workers don't have this problem.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker Private Registry: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177630/docker-private-registry-x509-certificate-signed-by-unknown-authority)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add an insecure docker registry, add the file `/etc/docker/daemon.json` (in Linux) with the following content:

```
{
    "insecure-registries" : [ "your.registry.host:5000" ]
}
```

and then you need to restart docker.

In case of Windows the file is at the following path: 
    `C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify I'm pulling images from a Windows machine.

Comment: However, adding it as an insecure docker registry through Windows Docker settings made it work, **although that step isn't needed to download Linux containers**.
Please edit the answer to include Windows solution and I'll accept it

Answer (score 7):

In windows you can find that file in

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\windows-daemon-options.json

Make the suggested changes by Nicola Ben and then restart the docker.